# Razor view Engine in Blazor (Convert blazor component to html string at run-time)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to get the generate the pdf in server-side Blazor. I use DinkToPdf as an external library to convert HTML string to pdf. But I'm having trouble of converting the blazor component to HTML string.

There is a way to render Razor templates to a string by using the Razor ViewEngine. From this web http://fizzylogic.nl/2017/08/03/how-to-generate-pdf-documents-in-asp-net-core/

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePDF()
{
    var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
    {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
        Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
        DocumentTitle = "PDF Report",
    };

    var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
    {
        PagesCount = true,
        HtmlContent = "<h>Hello World</h>",
        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8"},
        HeaderSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
        FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Line = true, Center = "Report Footer" }
    };

    var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
        Objects = { objectSettings }
    };

    var file = _converter.Convert(pdf);
    return File(file,"application/pdf");
}
```

I need to modify the ObjectSettings.HtmlContent to be my blazor component html string.

Comment: So to get this straight, what are you using server side blazor for? Are you using it just to render your pdfs? Are you trying to convert your web pages to pdfs? I can't see where your importing any view information into the html to render here, I'm a bit confused

Comment: Just for fun to use the server side blazor, since it is easy to convert it back by changing a couple line of codes. And that's correct, I'm trying to "print" my web page. But not just print, I want to customize it with my other blazor component or blazor template.

Comment: The goal is to generate a pdf by my blazor component (or view in Razor). The problem I have now is there are no such kinds of view Engine in blazor such that I can easily convert blazor view to html string.
Workflow: blazor view =(?)=> html string =(by DinkToPdf library)=> pdf

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to convert content the user can see? If so, you could add `@ref='ContentToRender'` to the component you want to render, Blazor will then assign that reference after the component is rendered:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div @ref=ContentToRender>
  ... Your content here...
</div>

@code {
  ElementReference ContentToRender;

  protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) 
  {
    if (firstRender) 
    {
      string html = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("BlazorUniversity.getInnerHTML", ContentToRender);
    }
  };
}
```

Where the JS would look something like this

```
var BlazorUniversity = BlazorUniversity || {};
BlazorUniversity.getInnerHTML = function(element) {
  return element.innerHTML;
};
```

Don't forget to include the JS in your main index.html or _Host.cshtml page.

For more info see [Passing HTML Element References](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/) on Blazor University.

Note that you will not be able to access the content until at least after the first render event (firstRender == true).

Comment: what if i want to create an instance of the component in .cs file directly and don't want to render it in view file.

JobSummaryCard card = new JobSummaryCard(); // component
card.CardModel = infoWindowJob; // parameter

but the ElementReference ContentToRender is always null in this case. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

......
        HtmlContent = TemplateGenerator.GetHTMLString(),
......

```
    public static string GetHTMLString()
    {
        IRaumNodeProvider RaumNodeProvider = new 
              RaumNodeProvider(Globals.Connectionstring);

        var reservierungen = RaumNodeProvider.GetReservierungen();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"
                    <html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <div class='header'><h1>Reservierungsliste</h1></div>
                            <table align='center'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id      </th>
                                    <th>Raum    </th>
                                    <th>Datum   </th>
                                    <th>Zeit    </th>
                                    <th>Beleger </th>
                                    <th>Belegung</th>
                                    <th>EmailMsg</th>
                                </tr>");

        foreach (var res in reservierungen)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(@"<tr>
                                <td>{0}</td>
                                <td>{1}</td>
                                <td>{2}</td>
                                <td>{3}</td>
                                <td>{4}</td>
                                <td>{5}</td>
                                <td>{6}</td>
                              </tr>", 
                                res.Res_Id              
                              , res.RaumName                                  
                              , res.BelegungsDatumTxt   
                              , res.Zeit                
                              , res.Belegung_durch      
                              , res.Belegung            
                              , res.EmailMsg
                              );
        }

        sb.Append(@"
                            </table>
                        </body>
                    </html>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I do understand that I can use stringbuilder to do it. But is there a way to use my blazor view instead? Because that will be a lot of work to build the pdf by using StringBuilder. I mean you have your blazor component view when running the app, is that possible to grab that view and turn it into pure html string.

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig through some of the source code and this is what I found that works for static content (`RenderMode.Static`) (I haven't tested this with script tags or layout hierarchies or nested components).

Depending on where you are trying to do this (i.e. within a request vs background task), you will either need to supply the current `HttpContext` or create your own.

```
public static async Task<string> RenderAsync<TComponent>(IHtmlHelper helper, HttpContext httpContext, object parameters)
{
  if (helper is IViewContextAware viewContextAware)
  {
    viewContextAware.Contextualize(new ViewContext()
    {
      HttpContext = httpContext
    }
  }

  var content = await helper.RenderComponentAsync<TComponent>(RenderMode.Static, parameters);
  var writer = new StringWriter();
  content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
  return writer.ToString();
}

public static HttpContext CreateDefaultContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  return new DefaultHttpContext
  {
    RequestServices = serviceProvider,
    Request =
    {
      Scheme = "http",
      Host = new HostString("localhost"),
      PathBase = "/base",
      Path = "/path",
      QueryString = QueryString.FromUriComponent("?query=value")
    }
  }
}
```

`CreateDefaultContext` is loosely based off of [this sample found in Microsoft's tests](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/test/RazorComponents/ComponentRendererTest.cs#L797-L815)

`Sample.razor`:

```
<h3>@Data.Title</h3>

Hello, @Data.FirstName @Data.LastName!

@code {

  [Parameter]
  public Test Data { get; set; }

  public class Test
  {
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }

}
```

Demo:

```
var helper = ServiceProvider.GetService<IHtmlHelper>();
var context = CreateDefaultContext(ServiceProvider);
var html = await RenderAsync<Sample>(helper, context, new
{
  Data = new Sample.Test()
  {
    Title = "Stack Overflow Test",
    FirstName = "user",
    LastName = "489566"
  }
});
```

html value:

```
<h3>Stack Overflow Test</h3>

Hello, user 489566!
```